# convert map to list<string> - as "key-value" to each list entry

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to convert `Map<Integer, String>` to `List<String>`
with each map entry - to 1 entry in the list as "key - value"

I searched and I only found to map values only to List.

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(10, "apple");
    map.put(20, "orange");
    map.put(30, "banana");
    map.put(40, "watermelon");
    map.put(50, "dragonfruit");
```

I want this to be mapped to list as

```
 "10-apple" 
 "20-orange"
```

and so on.

this can be done easily if I used foreach .. but I want to know if it is feasible to get it through streams

Comment: for fun:
List<String> strings=new ArrayList<>();
        map.entrySet().stream().peek(x->strings.add(x.getKey()+"-"+x.getValue())).collect(Collectors.counting());
        for (String s:strings) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

Comment: @SarelFoyerlicht seems hacky to me and abuses the `peek` operation. for fun, how about `map.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .map(e -> e.getKey() + "-" + e.getValue())
                .forEach(System.out::println);` ?

Comment: @Aominè everybody uses .stream() .map(...) so I try another way without it

Comment: @SarelFoyerlicht Right, but it's good practice to do things the "prefered" and "recommended" way, which in this specific case is to use `map` as shown in my previous comment instead of `peek`. plus you're also doing `.collect(Collectors.counting());` not that you care about the result but to only trigger the processing of the data which is not ideal IMO.

Comment: @Aominè interesting fact: peek will not work without collect(...), and by Java doc:**apiNote
This method exists mainly to support debugging, where you want to see the elements as they flow past a certain point in a pipeline...** so you are clearly right

Comment: "`peek` will not work without collect(...),". **exactly** hence my comment "plus you're also doing `.collect(Collectors.counting());` not that you care about the result **but to only trigger the processing of the data**". and regarding the quoted API note, hence my previous comment towards your code example of "seems hacky to me and abuses the `peek` operation.".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    List<String> list = map.entrySet()
                            .stream()
                            .map(entry -> entry.getKey() + "-" + entry.getValue())
                            .sorted()
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: although sorting it will yield the correct result in this specific example. it's not always guaranteed to work. it would be better to use `LinkedHashMap` in the first place since the iteration order is important then it would mean you no longer need the `sorted()` operation which as mentioned will not always yield the correct output.

Answer (score 2):

Just a slightly different variant to the other answers. if the insertion/iteration order is important then I'd rather use a `LinkedHashMap` in the first place as opposed to using a `HashMap` then sorting it which is actually not always guaranteed to work.

Example:

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
...
...
...
```

then stream over the entrySet and collect to a list implementation:

```
List<String> list = map.entrySet()
                        .stream()
                        .map(e -> e.getKey() + "-" + e.getValue())
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one variant using .map to move from list to map

```
List<String> list = map.entrySet()
                       .stream()
                       .map(x -> String.format("%d-%s", x.getKey().intValue(), x.getValue()))
                       .sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: although sorting it will yield the correct result in this specific example. it's not always guaranteed to work. it would be better to use `LinkedHashMap` in the first place since the iteration order is important then it would mean you no longer need the `sorted() `operation which as mentioned will not always yield the correct output.

Comment: That was hardly part of the question.

Comment: Then why are you sorting?

Answer (score -3):

if you want just the values of the Map try this

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(map.values())
```

{"apple", "orange"}

Comment: That's not the question